# When booting Ubuntu, I get the GRUB command line

Tags: grub2, usb, laptop, asus, rufus

So, I've had a Windows laptop for around 5-6 years. When I got my computer, I realised how laggy it was. So, I decided to install Linux Mint on it. I decided to change to Ubuntu because I liked the look of it more.

*I'm sorry if this is a bit off, I have to re-type this since this is on my laptop which means I can't just simply copy and paste.*

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

Thanks, if someone could help solve this, that would be great. I'd rather have to type in a couple commands instead of redownloading Ubuntu.

I have tried going to the boot menu, I tried normal Ubuntu and I assume the other was recovery Ubuntu because before when I had a problem during Ubuntu it looked a bit like the recovery Windows. *(meaning the resolution was lower.)*

I'm not booting it from a USB, I did installed it via a USB though. With and without the USB I used to install Ubuntu, the GRUB command line boots up.

> *If I didn't put enough details in or you need to find out something else about this problem, just comment and tell me. I'll edit this post
>   with the details asap.*

Comment: What brand/model system? And What video card/chip? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error. Instead of using rufus, I used UNetBootin to create the USB.